# My *ngFor is not working in Angular 11. Please help to solve this

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I am using `*ngFor` to get send array to `HTML` page from typescript.

```
kitUser: any=[];
  constructor(private service: AdminService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getKSignUps().subscribe(res=>{
      this.kitUser=res;
      console.log(this.kitUser);
    });
  }
```

And at htMl page,

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of kitUser ">
        <td>
          {{ item.kitchenName }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ item.kitchenNumber }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ item.kitchenEmail }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ item.kitchenPassword }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ item.kitchenAddress }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ item.kitchenDescription }}
        </td>
</tr>
```

But nothing is shown on the browser. I have tried a lot of different ways and came to a conclusion that my **`*ngFor`** is actually not working. Please help me with it.

Comment: What exactly does the thing you get back look like?

Comment: do you have `BrowserModule` added to your imports?

Comment: In addition to the above ... Do you see the data in the console from the `console.log`? Do you have onPush change detection set?

Comment: Check your console.log response in console, if you are able to see data in console then make sure that it should array of objects.

Comment: Yes, I am getting response in console.log, but don't know why ngFor is not iterating the result.

Answer (score 0):

If all the above comments did not work, maybe try this

```
export class KitchenUser {
kitchenName!: string;
kitchenNumber!: string;
kitchenEmail!: string;
kitchenPassword!: string;
  kitchenAddress!: string;
  kitchenDescription!: string;
}
```

```
 kitchenUsers!: KitchenUser [];
  constructor(private service: AdminService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getKSignUps().subscribe((res: KitchenUser[]) => {
      this.kitchenUsers= res;
      console.log(this.kitchenUsers);
    });
```

```
<tr *ngFor="let kitchenuser of kitchenUsers ">
  <td>
    {{ kitchenuser.kitchenName }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Let us know if this didn't help. Please post any error messages from the VS code debug console and from the console in your browser.

Take care & good luck.